# Centering the image in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

I m using bootstrap 3.0 to creating a website. I am new to bootstrap. what i want, i want image in center of div when browser size is extra small i have this code.

```
<div class="col-lg-10 ccol-lg-offset-1 col-md-12 col-sm-12 ">
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
        <img src="images/2.png" class="img-responsive" />
        <p class="text-center"><a href="javascript:void(0);">Taj Group</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2  col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
        <img src="images/2.png" class="img-responsive" />
        <p class="text-center"><a href="javascript:void(0);">Taj Group</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2  col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
        <img src="images/2.png" class="img-responsive" />
        <p class="text-center"><a href="javascript:void(0);">Taj Group</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2  col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
        <img src="images/2.png" class="img-responsive" />
        <p class="text-center"><a href="javascript:void(0);">Taj Group</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
        <img src="images/2.png" class="img-responsive" />
        <p class="text-center"><a href="javascript:void(0);">Taj Group</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
        <img src="images/2.png" class="img-responsive" />
        <p class="text-center"><a href="javascript:void(0);">Taj Group</a></p>
    </div>
```

Comment: try this `<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12 text-center">`

Comment: @Morpheus not working :(

Comment: How do you know it's not working? You are using `class="img-responsive"` for image and it takes full width of the div. Try to remove this class and see what happens.

Comment: i want img-responsive class to my html sir, i dont want to remove this class

Comment: in this case your problem is not a problem as the image should take full width of your div.

Comment: Note you don't need all those classes, using just `col-sm-2` will suffice

Answer (score 166, accepted):

### Update 2018

**Bootstrap 2.x**

You could create a new CSS class such as:

```
.img-center {margin:0 auto;}
```

And then, add this to each IMG:

```
 <img src="images/2.png" class="img-responsive img-center">
```

OR, just override the `.img-responsive` if you're going to center all images..

```
 .img-responsive {margin:0 auto;}
```

Demo: **http://bootply.com/86123**

**Bootstrap 3.x**

***EDIT*** - With the release of Bootstrap 3.0.1, the `center-block` class can now be used without any additional CSS..

```
 <img src="images/2.png" class="img-responsive center-block">
```

---

**Bootstrap 4**

In Bootstrap 4, the `mx-auto` class (auto x-axis margins) can be used to center images that are `display:block`. However, img is `display:inline` by default so `text-center` can be used on the parent.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <img class="mx-auto d-block" src="//placehold.it/200">  
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 text-center">
            <img src="//placehold.it/200">  
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Bootsrap 4 - center image demo](https://www.codeply.com/go/ksWIufgfkS)

Answer (score 1):

```
.img-responsive {
     margin: 0 auto;
 }
```

you can write like above code in your document so no need to add one another class in image tag.

Answer (score -3):

Use This as the solution

This worked for me perfectly..

```
<div align="center">
   <img src="">
</div>
```

Comment: The <div> align attribute is not supported in HTML5.